# Why is the clock_gettime in C++ giving me different values compared to Java nanotime()

Tags: java, c++

So I have this old piece of code that I used to use when implementing a jump in Java games.

It looks something like this:

```
//Vars
final int Y_ZERO_POINT = 580;
double height = 0, speed = 4;
public static final double gravity = 9.81;
double x = 25;
int y = (int) (Y_ZERO_POINT-(height*100));
long previous, start = 0;

// Code in my game loop
        start = System.nanoTime();

        if(previous != 0 && up){
            double delta = start - previous;
            height = (height + (delta/1000000000) * speed);        
            speed -= (delta/1000000000)  * gravity;
            y = (int) (Y_ZERO_POINT-(height * 100));

        }
        previous = start;
```

Now I wanted to implement something similar in a C++ game.
Reading here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/what-is-behind-systemnanotime.html
I learned that the Java `System.getNanoTime()` uses `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);` in Linux systems.

So I used it in my C++ code and implemented the same jump code:
https://github.com/Veske/CPP-Learning/blob/master/kodutoo3/player/player.cpp

And the difference is huge. In Java the jump is always consistent and ends like it should. In my C++ program, the jump sometimes acts just like in Java but mostly it will have radical changes in it. The time I get from `clock_gettime()` jumps a lot sometimes and that causes the jump it self in the game to also look very random. The character can sometimes jump out of the screen and then the next time jump normally again.

Is it possible to have a consistent result from the C++ time function just like in Java or should I think about using a different approach for my jump mechanic?

Comment: The core issue is that your only looking at the tv_nsec field, which is only the fractional seconds.  You need to combine it with the tv_sec field as well.  But the recommended solution is to use <chrono> as shown by @865719

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a C++11 compiler, you can use the portable [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) header.

[[run it online](http://cpp.sh/7uq7g)]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto t0 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dt = t1 - t0;

    cout << "t0: " << chrono::time_point_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(t0).time_since_epoch().count() << " ns" << endl;
    cout << "t1: " << chrono::time_point_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(t1).time_since_epoch().count() << " ns" << endl;
    cout << "dt: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(dt).count() << " ns" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
t0: 2800906746162 ns
t1: 2800906746345 ns
dt: 183 ns
```

For time-difference measurement, make sure to use a *non-adjustable* (a.k.a. *monotonic*) clock like [`steady_clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/steady_clock/). More info [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/14/cpp-11-timing-code-performance/).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!