# c++ local time without impact from daylight savings using boost

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I am having a system that has some logic that depends on the time past. I was about to start testing it against daylight savings when I realized since I am using the time more just to evaluate a duration and I do not care if the time is precise or not I can avoid issues with the daylight savings completely if my API returns the time unaffected from it.

Note my project is multi-platform long running server (more than 43. something days) - I do not want to use tick counter that might restart.

My question is how I can use boost to give me current local (or whatever) time without daylight savings reflected (that might cause a big jump two times per year).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`boost::chrono::steady_clock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/chrono/users_guide.html)

[Here are some examples](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.chrono)

**NB**: If you have a C++11 compiler, you can skip boost in favor of the new, standard and portable [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) header. Check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980562/865719).

Comment: This looks like exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can just count the number of second since 1/1/1970 its not dependent of daytime :

```
#include <time.h>

time_t seconds_past_epoch = time(0);
```

Available on most operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Use Posix Time (Epoch)
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html
It's absolute and you can convert it to or from a local timezone somewhat trivially.